# IE9 not display correctly, is my html header correct?

Tags: css, header, internet-explorer-9

I ask this because I don't know why in IE9 my site looks like this:

[image]

And another broswers display correctly:

[image]

I was assuming it was due to poor position in the header files but not exactly this happening and that's the last part of my project, it looks good in IE9.

**General structure of my index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <?php include 'configHead.php' ?>
    <title>Panel de Servicio</title>
</head>
<body>
.......
</body>
```

**configHead.php**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="media/favicon.png" />
<script src="js/prefixfree.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css" type="text/css"/>

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: add `<!doctype html>` at the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have **any** comments or any text above your `<!DOCTYPE html>` ... remove the comment on top and your site will work fine in IE .. Its currently triggering your page to go into quirks mode (which is roughly equivalent to IE5) .. as far as IE is concerned you have no doctype.

Right now you have this comment:

```
<!--Aplicación: Sistema de tickets y pólizas.
Cliente: MA Consulting.
Desarrollador: XXX XXX XXX
Twitter: @_xxx
Email: xxx@gmail.com
Fecha: Julio/2012 - Febrero/2013
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Before your doctype .. move that comment **after** `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Sure, I'll make the changes and answer

Comment: Works, thanks :) But I have a question.. hoy do you get the block comment that put in your answer?

Comment: I mean that how get this code of my system but, I did not realize that in the picture above was the url and saw the source code there: P

Comment: Last question, if I want include modernizr.js I can put before this line? <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>